# Nginx Config for SSL PHP site & Websockets WSS?

Tags: php, nginx, websocket

I'm trying to setup a websocket connection (wss). My domain uses ssl (certbot) and is powered by Nginx. I am unsure how to configure my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` file.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
...
}
```

I added the following into my config block:

```
location /websocket {
    proxy_pass         https://example.com;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

When connecting via: `wss://example.com/`, I am getting an error of

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Most of the examples out there are using a nodejs framework to serve their sites, but I am using php. Are there any tutorials out there that can guide me, or does anyone have an idea how to configure my config file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find `proxy_pass         https://example.com;` in your nginx config, howerever `https://example.com` is http server instead of websocket server, so you got response code 200

this is an example

```
location ~ ^/websocket/(.*$) {
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout  1200s 1200s;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:51966/$1;
    proxy_read_timeout 1200s;
    proxy_send_timeout 1200s;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

51966 is the port that websocket is listening

Comment: I tried this and it was still giving me a similar error. I'll google and study more tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: `wss://example.com/websocket/`   this should be helpful  and change the config `location /websocket` to `location ~^ /websocket`  swould be better

Comment: Thank you. I had forgot to setup my supervisord. This helped.